# Adding wp_list_categories to a specific div that was appended using jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, categories

Due to the way my projects menu is coded/styled I'm having some difficulty figuring this out.
I have appended a div to my menu using jQuery, and I want to be able to include an external php file that simply contains a wp_list_categories(); function wrapped in an unordered list. What would be the best way to go about doing this so that wordpress recognises the wp_list_categories functions and works as I've intended? or is there a better/easier solution.

Comment: perhaps you should back up a bit and explain why you need to append a div via javascript to create your menu. I have a feeling there's a better solution to that problem which will eliminate this problem.

Comment: @Milo I'm trying to achieve a drop-down effect for my menu, where if a user hovers over a menu item its children in the menu display - for one specific menu item there has to be an entire full-width div that spans across the entire menu (where I wish to display different categories). Apologies if it doesn't make sense, I've included the following picture that might help get across what I'm trying to do.

http://i.imgur.com/e8f34zD.jpg

Comment: assuming this is a `wp_nav_menu`, I suggest searching around a bit on this site and elsewhere for custom [menu walkers](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/Walker_Class) and the various filters available for nav menus, like [`wp_nav_menu_objects`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu#How_to_add_a_parent_class_for_menu_item). you can inject the div and categories all at once when the menu is output, no javascript necessary. Give it a shot and update your question with code if you need further help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`wp_localize_script`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script) to pass PHP data to Javascript. Store the result in a variable by setting the `echo` parameter of `wp_list_categories()` to `false`, and then pass the variable in the object you send to javascript through `wp_localize_script`.

On a side note, I am not sure why you are having this problem at all, honestly: can you not hide your dropdowns with CSS? Or even [`detach`](http://api.jquery.com/detach/) them with jQuery on `jQuery(document).ready()`, to reapply them when you need them?

Comment: You're absolutely right, I'm not sure why I didn't think of this earlier. Thank you for explaining the wp_localize_script method to me though.